# Why Wifi no longer works 12.04.1?

Tags: wireless

Starting this morning over wifi (Realtek RTL8188CE) on CLEVO W253HU.
May be due to the update before yesterday, more pilot managed, but somehow it worked yesterday.
If someone has an idea of the problem.

Back command lines:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 192f:0416 Avago Technologies, Pte. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:0315 Acer, Inc

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 05)
03:00.1 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 90)
03:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 90)
03:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 90)

lspci -nn | grep -i net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [197b:0250] (rev 05)

lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 9196
    Kernel modules: rtl8192ce
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel driver in use: jme
    Kernel modules: jme
03:00.1 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 90)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci-pci
03:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 90)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel modules: sdhci-pci
03:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 90)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 4140
    Kernel driver in use: jmb38x_ms
    Kernel modules: jmb38x_ms

sudo lshw -C network
  *-network NON-RÉCLAMÉ   
       description: Network controller
       produit: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       ressources: portE/S:e000(taille=256) mémoire:f7d00000-f7d03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabriquant: JMicron Technology Corp.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nom logique: eth0
       version: 05
       numéro de série: 00:90:f5:c1:c6:45
       taille: 100Mbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 32 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm pciexpress msix msi bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=jme driverversion=1.0.8 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.54 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       ressources: irq:44 mémoire:f7c20000-f7c23fff portE/S:d100(taille=128) portE/S:d000(taille=256) mémoire:f7c10000-f7c1ffff mémoire:f7c00000-f7c0ffff

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
btusb                  18288  0 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bnep                   18281  2 
bluetooth             180104  11 btusb,rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32866  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   224173  0 
dm_crypt               23125  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  0 
uvcvideo               72627  0 
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
snd_hda_intel          33773  2 
snd_hda_codec         127706  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97188  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
jmb38x_ms              17646  0 
psmouse                87692  0 
serio_raw              13211  0 
memstick               16569  1 jmb38x_ms
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
rtl8192ce              84826  0 
rtl8192c_common        75767  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi               111202  1 rtl8192ce
snd_seq                61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
mac80211              506816  3 rtl8192ce,rtl8192c_common,rtlwifi
mac_hid                13253  0 
snd                    78855  14 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
cfg80211              205544  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
mei                    41616  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 47199  0 
hid                    99559  1 usbhid
i915                  473035  3 
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 i915
drm                   242038  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
jme                    41259  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 i915
sdhci_pci              18826  0 
sdhci                  33205  1 sdhci_pci
wmi                    19256  0 
video                  19596  1 i915

iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:f5:c1:c6:45  
          inet adr:192.168.1.54  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::290:f5ff:fec1:c645/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:4513 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4359 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:3471675 (3.4 MB) Octets transmis:712722 (712.7 KB)
          Interruption:44 

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:686 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:686 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
          Octets reçus:64556 (64.5 KB) Octets transmis:64556 (64.5 KB)

sudo iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

uname -r -m
3.2.0-30-generic x86_64

cat  /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Connexion filaire 1] ------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            jme
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:90:F5:C1:C6:45

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.54
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

sudo rfkill listrfkill list
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

The absence of line "Kernel driver in use:" the return of lspci-k made ​​me think that it is not loaded yet but he seems to be.
lsmod | grep rtl8192ce
rtl8192ce             137478  0 
rtlwifi               118749  1 rtl8192ce
mac80211              506816  2 rtl8192ce,rtlwifi

I found something disturbing in / var / log / syslog
Sep 14 11:40:11 pcroger kernel: [   64.048783] rtl8192ce-0:rtl92c_init_sw_vars():<0-0> Failed to request firmware!
Sep 14 11:40:11 pcroger kernel: [   64.048795] rtlwifi-0:rtl_pci_probe():<0-0> Can't init_sw_vars.
Sep 14 11:40:11 pcroger kernel: [   64.048835] rtl8192ce 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
Sep 14 11:40:11 pcroger kernel: [   64.943345] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x7fffffff SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Sep 14 11:40:11 pcroger kernel: [   64.943358] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Sep 14 11:40:11 pcroger kernel: [   64.943371] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:00:00:68:6a/04:00:0b:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 524288 in
Sep 14 11:40:11 pcroger kernel: [   64.943374]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Sep 14 11:40:11 pcroger kernel: [   64.943381] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
```

Ubuntu and takes forever to start (2 min).

Answer (score 1):

Somehow your kernel module is unable to locate the required firmware file. Quoting your log: `Failed to request firmware!`

If it worked before, something may have caused the packages `linux-firmware` and `linux-firmware-nonfree` to be removed, or even the whole `multiverse` section of the Ubuntu repository might be purged.

So, try installing these packages again (and reboot afterwards - or reload kernel module):

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-firmware linux-firmware-nonfree
```

If that doesn't help, try also instructions in [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=66520) Debian forum post in which the same issue is being resolved by moving around the location of the firmware file.

Comment: Hello and thank you
I did sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-linux-nonfree firmware but nothing has changed except that I have no line containing rtl8192ce rtlwifi or in the logs.

I have a lot of log failed command: READ QUEUED FPDMA it can not come from that?

The debian bug http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=613536 date 02/2011 but I everything worked well so far.
Updated 12.04.1 and since bugs.

I think everything reinstalled livecd.
When do you think?

Cordially.